# New project files requiring the import of UIKit

Tags: swift, frameworks, xcode6, uikit

I have a project A, which I started writing with Swift1-Xcode6. I have some extension files like:

```
extension UIView {
    convenience init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, w: CGFloat, h: CGFloat) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h))
    }
}
```

I created a new project B and copied these extension files in there. I am getting this error:

```
UIViewExtensions.swift:11:11: Use of undeclared type 'UIView'
```

Files in Project-A do not need the inclusion of UIKit, but Project-B does. What is the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This probably happens because you import some Objective-C Frameworks in your bridging header that happens to import UIKit in its .h file - which automatically imports UIKit to all your Swift classes

Answer (score 4):

`UIView` is defined in the UIKit framework, so a Swift file using
that class needs to `import UIKit`.

But since all Swift files import the (Swift mapping of the) 
*bridging header file*, it would also be sufficient if the bridging header file directly or indirectly imports the UIKit framework.

That could be the reason why you did not have to import it *explicitly*
in the Swift file in your older project.